# How can I change background color of web page from drop down using javascript need this

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I need help regarding JavaScript function code where I want to change the background-color of a web page from drop down list. When someone select any color from the list then it responds as same and change the background color of web page. I used the technique in JS is DOM. How we can done this.
Here is my code for this task:-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var change;

    function colour() {
      document.bgcolor = change.themes.val();
    }
    colour();
  </script>
</head>
<title>Best Themes</title>

<body>
  <form action="onchange(colour)" name="themes" method="post">
    <select name="colors">
    <option value="white" selected="select">White</option>
    <option value="black">Black</option>
    <option value="orange">Orange</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="skyblue">Sky Blue</option>
    <option value="pink">Pink</option>
    <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
    <option value="mustard">Mustard</option>
    <option value="maroon">Maroon</option>
    <option value="magenta">Magenta</option>
    <option value="cyan">Cyan</option>
    <option value="gray">Gray</option>
    <option value="seagreen">Sea Green</option>
    <option value="chocolate">Chocolate</option>
    <option value="fuchsia">Fuchsia</option>
    <option value="gold">Gold</option>
    <option value="khaki">Khaki</option>
    <option value="silver">Silver</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Note-filename save as theme.html

Help please, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You were not calling the `onChange` function
2. The `onChange` function was set to the form and not the `select`
3. You need `document.body.style.backgroundColor` to change the background color of the body
4. You were using `change.themes` based on `var change` which is never used elsewhere and never set

```js
function changeColor(el) {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = el.value;
}
```

```html
<select name="colors" onchange="changeColor(this)">
<option value="white" selected="select">White</option>
<option value="black">Black</option>
<option value="orange">Orange</option>
<option value="green">Green</option>
<option value="blue">Blue</option>
<option value="skyblue">Sky Blue</option>
<option value="pink">Pink</option>
<option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
<option value="mustard">Mustard</option>
<option value="maroon">Maroon</option>
<option value="magenta">Magenta</option>
<option value="cyan">Cyan</option>
<option value="gray">Gray</option>
<option value="seagreen">Sea Green</option>
<option value="chocolate">Chocolate</option>
<option value="fuchsia">Fuchsia</option>
<option value="gold">Gold</option>
<option value="khaki">Khaki</option>
<option value="silver">Silver</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `onchange` to the `select` element. It does not need to come with `form action`
This snippet may be useful

```
// get the selector & add `onchange` function to it.
// Here changeEventHandler will be executed when there is a change in select
document.querySelector('select[name="colors"]').onchange = changeEventHandler;


function changeEventHandler(event) {
  if (!event.target.value) {} else {
    // targeting body to change color
    // event.target will be the select element
    // event.target.value will the option selected from dropdown
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = event.target.value;
  }
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/xqqobuxw/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
    function color() {
      var color = document.getElementById("colors").value; // cached
// The working function for changing background color.
    document.bgColor = color;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>
<title>Best Themes</title>

<body id="coltext">
  <form action="" name="themes" method="post">
    <select name="colors" id="colors" onchange="color()">
    <option value="white" selected="select">White</option>
    <option value="black">Black</option>
    <option value="orange">Orange</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="skyblue">Sky Blue</option>
    <option value="pink">Pink</option>
    <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
    <option value="mustard">Mustard</option>
    <option value="maroon">Maroon</option>
    <option value="magenta">Magenta</option>
    <option value="cyan">Cyan</option>
    <option value="gray">Gray</option>
    <option value="seagreen">Sea Green</option>
    <option value="chocolate">Chocolate</option>
    <option value="fuchsia">Fuchsia</option>
    <option value="gold">Gold</option>
    <option value="khaki">Khaki</option>
    <option value="silver">Silver</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

First you are not assigning value to `change`

```
var change;

function colour() {
  document.bgcolor = change.themes.val();
}
```

change this to

```
function color() {
  var color = document.getElementById("colors").value; // cached
// The working function for changing background color.
document.bgColor = color;
}
```

Next you are calling onchange in the wrong place
`<form action="onchange(colour)" name="themes" method="post">`
change this to 

`<form action="yourAction" name="themes" method="post">`

and
`<select name="colors">`-to

`<select name="colors" id="colors" onchange="color()">`

hope this helps.